# DynamicForm Component that takes Generic Model Class as Parameter to Generate EditForm

Tags: reflection, blazor, blazor-editform

I have a component called DynamicForm which accepts couple of Parameters including Generic Model Class.

```
@typeparam TModel

<EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="@HandleFormSubmit">
    @foreach (var property in typeof(TModel).GetProperties())
    {
        @if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            <input class="form-control" id="@property.Name" @bind="@property.GetValue(Model)" />
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="@property.Name" @bind="@property.GetValue(Model)" />
        }
    }

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public TModel Model { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<TModel> OnValidSubmit { get; set; }

    private Task HandleFormSubmit()
    {
        return OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync(Model);
    }
}
```

what I am trying to achive is to generate Dynamic EditForm (Controls) based on Provided Model Class using following code

```
<DynamicForm TModel="FormModel" Model="@person" OnValidSubmit="HandleFormSubmit" />

@code {
    private FormModel person = new FormModel();

    private void HandleFormSubmit(FormModel model)
    {
        //Todo
    }
}
```

But I am getting following compile time errors on `@bind="@property.GetValue(Model)"`

- Error (active)    CS0131  The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer
- Error (active)    CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.DateTime'

Answer (score 1):

You cannot value bind like this.

Rather do something like this:

```
<input
    type="text"
    value="@property.GetValue(Model)"
    @onchange="(e) => property.SetValue(Model, e.Value)" />
```

You set the value of the DOM input element using its `value` attribute.
You set the object's property value using Blazor's `@onchange` `EventCallback`. The first parameter is of type `ChangeEventArgs` and contains a property called `Value` with a type of `string`.

Remember to cast your strings to their appropriate types.

I do however recommend you create input components or use Blazor's built in components.

Comment: I think This approach will not work with 3rd party UI Component Providers such as Radzen, can you please give me an example or link to create Custom Input Components which covers Select/MultiSelect and more advanced controls.

Comment: @AlisbhaKhan Why not ? They usually have a one way binding parameter and onchange event handler (`Value` and `Change` respectively for RadzenTextBox for instance)

Comment: @AlisbhaKhan Radzen uses `Value` and `ValueChanged` parameters. Just use those.